# How to set number of copies to be print?

Tags: vb.net, printing, vb.net-2010

I am following this [Edraw Link](https://www.edrawsoft.com/embed-word-vbnet.php) and I able to do what he said in he's blog except for the code in `btnNew`. BTW I am trying to add a numbers to be print when user input any numbers in a text box.

This is my code in print so far

```
With AxEDOffice1
        // here I want to get the value of the inputed value from the textbox that input from the user.(number of copies to be print)
        .SetActivePrinter("Printer Name")
        .PrintOut(EDOfficeLib.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument)
End With
```

Comment: Have you tried a loop?

Comment: @OneFineDay no. I didn't think about it. haha. I was focus on thinking about the code in setting the number of copies.